# Shake functionality in a music application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio-player

I have developed a small music app by using AVPlayer and MPMediaPickerControlLibrary with all the normal required functionalities for a music app. The app is also capable of running in the background when the screen is locked.

Now, what I want is to start the app when the screen is locked through a shake and soon as the app starts the current song should start playing.
I am not able to achieve this from a long time
Any suggestions on this will be highly appreciated or any other workaround apart from shake to turn on the music in the app when the screen is locked in iPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the a CMMotionManager object, but keeping it running all the time in background will be a major power consumption issue.
Modifying the updateInterval property to reduce the number of updates will defeat the purpose, given that you may miss a shake in background.

Now, if the app was terminated by the user, then no motionManager object will be available until the user launches the app again.